# Django jQuery get sending logged in users data

Tags: django, jquery, django-templates

I am trying to send my logged in users details along with this request, as I am making use of a `if else endif` statement on the requested page to render some buttons, ie "add a new item"

My jQuery code looks as follows:

```
$('.wall').click(function(){
    $('#loading').show();
    $.get(this.href, { request.user: request.user }, function(data){
        $("#wall-tabs").html(data);
        $('#loading').hide();
    });
    $(".wall").find("span").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).find("span").addClass("selected");
    return false;
});
```

This `$.get(this.href, { request.user: request.user }, function(data){` seems to break it, however if I remove the data in between the brackets it works, but I am not seeing the buttons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you need to specify a parameter name in your data map.  So, instead of:

```
$.get(this.href, { request.user: request.user }, function(data){
```

You would have:

```
$.get(this.href, { parameter_name : request.user }, function(data){
```

Where parameter_name is the name of the get variable the page you are requesting expects to receive.

Take a look at the jQuery docs, about midway down the page:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the syntax used to pick up the variables. You'll need *two* curly brackets to pick up the variable in the template. Something like this: `{{ request.user }}`.

<strike>However I am not sure that you can include it directly as there is an obvious clash with the JS syntax. You might want to collect `{{ request.user }}` into a variable and then use it in the dictionary.</strike>

Comment: Why would the syntax conflict? Template variables are resolved before the page is sent to the client, so the javascript would only see the rendered variable.

Comment: Thanks. My mistake. I was not thinking straight.